# Producing XML hash in a WCF Web Service client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have been tasked with creating a C# .net WCF web service client that will consume a web service for a transaction gateway. Part of the requirements is that I  must create a HMAC hash of a number of values and inject these values into the HTTP header. I believe I have most of it figured out but the one portion of the data that has me puzzled is that one of the values needed for the HMAC hash is a SHA-1 hash of the actual contents of the transaction. Since I am building this using SOAP using a service reference this data is XML. My question is how to hash the XML that makes up this transaction?

Can anyone provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this a standard protocol? If so, then it may already be implemented, either by Microsoft or by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this isn't a protocol that's already implemented by MS or someone else per @John Saunders suggestion, you could roll your own by wiring up an instance of [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx).

The message inspector gives you access to the raw SOAP message before you send it, which would allow you to hash it and append it to the headers.

[This blog post details adding custom headers using the IClientMessageInspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/02/25/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is standard protocol. I saw where I could use the iClientMessageInspector to access the headers but did not realize I could access the SOAP message with that as well. I will look into this. Thanks for your suggestions all.